# How to create carousel div bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I create this carousel in Bootstrap 3? I want to slide at one time one div, not three. I tried exchange the normal carousel images with divs, but it's not working correctly.

I want somenthing like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwVKw.gif

Comment: bootstrap customization for this is a pain, have you seen bxslider? not to ad another lib, but its super easy: http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified
you want example 4

Answer (score -1):

What you need is set [overflow-x: scroll](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp) for your grid and set fixed width for it.

And then via butoons scrool to next item (use `$(".wheelGrid").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos}, height);`)